# How do you setup a Synapse Serverless SQL External Table over partitioned data?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have setup a Synapse workspace and imported the Covid19 sample data into a PySpark notebook.

```
blob_account_name = "pandemicdatalake"
blob_container_name = "public"
blob_relative_path = "curated/covid-19/bing_covid-19_data/latest/bing_covid-19_data.parquet"
blob_sas_token = r""
# Allow SPARK to read from Blob remotely
wasbs_path = 'wasbs://%s@%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s' % (blob_container_name, blob_account_name, blob_relative_path)

spark.conf.set(
    'fs.azure.sas.%s.%s.blob.core.windows.net' % (blob_container_name, blob_account_name),
    blob_sas_token)
df = spark.read.parquet(wasbs_path)
```

I have then partitioned the data by country_region, and written it back down into my storage account.

```
df.write.partitionBy("country_region") /
    .mode("overwrite") /
    .parquet("abfss://rawdata@synapsepoc.dfs.core.windows.net/synapsepoc/Covid19/")
```

[image]

All that works fine as you can see. So far I have only found a way to query data from the exact partition using OPENROWSET, like this...

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://synapsepoc.dfs.core.windows.net/synapsepoc/Covid19/country_region=Afghanistan/**',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
```

I want to setup an Serverless SQL External table over the partition data, so that when people run a query and use "WHERE country_region = x" it will only read the appropriate partition. Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

You need to [get the partition value using the `filepath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/create-use-views#partitioned-views) function like this. Then filter on it. That achieves partition elimination. You can confirm by the bytes read compared to when you don’t filter on that column.

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
As
SELECT
    *, filepath(1) as country_region
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://synapsepoc.dfs.core.windows.net/synapsepoc/Covid19/country_region=*/*',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]

GO

Select * from MyView where country_region='Afghanistan'
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same but having external table instead of view?

Comment: @czajek not that I’m aware of